# How to make my app support retina display

Tags: ios, ipad, retina-display

I am Developing an ipad app and would like to support the new retina display. What do i need to do in order to make my app retina support?

Thanks

Comment: Start reading the docs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation from Apple on the portal you'll find the new icon sizes that you need to support in order to target that platform. The important part are the icons big resolutions, if you are using images inside the application. Make sure you use high dpi

Hope this helps
Cheers
Al